# redeclaring method when i try to mock it

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, mocking, facade

i have a class that is binded in service provider
this class uses my facade which extends the laravel's facade,but
when i try to mock the class it say's
`Cannot redeclare Mockery_1_App_Classes_Dashboard_class::shouldReceive()`.
my test method:

```
    public function test_method()
    {
        class::shouldReceive('method')->once()->andReturns(true);

        $response = $this->another_class->method();

        dd($response);
    }
```

my facade :

```
<?php

namespace App\Facades\Dashboard;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class class extends Facade
{
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
    {
        return 'class';
    }
}
```

AppServiceProvider :

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

use App\Classes\Dashboard\class;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('class', function($app) {
            return new class;
        });
    }

    public function boot()
    {
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
    }
}
```

i searched the web, unfortunately haven't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally found the problem.
i was accidentally extending laravel's facade in my class inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be sure about your class which you called to mock. You have to import class namespace directly to test file. Not import from facedes or from another namespace. Use normal namespace. It could be about that but I believe that, mock could not find the correct class.

Right import :

```
use \App\xxx\xxx\ConfirmationParserService;
```

Wrong import

```
use Facades\App\xxx\xxx\ConfirmationParserService;
```

Both of them calling same class but second one is calling with mediator.